# displaying xml data in html page

Tags: javascript, html, xml

My home page:

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="read.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body onload="process()">


    <div id="theD" />





</body>

</html>
```

and the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CategoriesRoot>
    <Categories>
        <CategoryID>1</CategoryID>
        <CategoryName>Beverages</CategoryName>
        <Description>Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beer, and ale</Description>
    </Categories>
    <Categories>
        <CategoryID>2</CategoryID>
        <CategoryName>Condiments</CategoryName>
        <Description>Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads, and seasonings</Description>
    </Categories>
    <Categories>
        <CategoryID>3</CategoryID>
        <CategoryName>Confections</CategoryName>
        <Description>Desserts, candies, sweetbreads</Description>
    </Categories>
    <Categories>
        <CategoryID>4</CategoryID>
        <CategoryName>Dairy Products</CategoryName>
        <Description>Cheeses</Description>
    </Categories>
    <Categories>
        <CategoryID>5</CategoryID>
        <CategoryName>Grains/Cereals</CategoryName>
        <Description>Breads, crackers, pasta, and cereal</Description>
    </Categories>
    <Categories>
        <CategoryID>6</CategoryID>
        <CategoryName>Meat/Poultry</CategoryName>
        <Description>Prepared meats</Description>
    </Categories>
    <Categories>
        <CategoryID>7</CategoryID>
        <CategoryName>Produce</CategoryName>
        <Description>Dried fruit and bean curd</Description>
    </Categories>
    <Categories>
        <CategoryID>8</CategoryID>
        <CategoryName>Seafood</CategoryName>
        <Description>Seaweed and fish</Description>
    </Categories>
</CategoriesRoot>
```

and the js file:

```
function process()
{
var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {

    names=xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("CategoryName");
    var stuff ;
    for (var i=0;i<names.length;i++)
      {
        stuff = names.item(i).firstChild.data + "<br/>";

      }
         theD = document.getElementById("theD");
         theD.innerHTML = stuff;

    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","categories.xml",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

the problem is when I run the home page, it just displays seafood on the screen.
I can not find out where I make mistake. I need to display all the categoryname.
please help!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: `stuff` is overwritten in every step of the loop, so when you add `stuff` to the DOM after the loop, it only contains the last value, the others were overwritten.

Comment: can you modify my code, i am new in this field. thank you so much!

Comment: `stuff += names.item(i).firstChild.data + "<br/>";` add a plus ?

Comment: But...another problem show up...the result is undefinedBeverages. why it is undefined? how to fix it?

Comment: The first one is probably undefined, try starting at 1 instead -> `var i=1`

Comment: var i=1 still the first one is undefined..